# How to Pass Props to Class Using VueJS Render Function

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

The following code works:

```
export default {
    props: ['tag', 'type', 'size', 'color', 'direction'],
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(
            this.tag || 'div',
            {
                attrs: { class: 'ui label'}
            },
            this.$slots.default
        );
    }
}
```

I can create the following html tag and it renders properly:

```
<label-x tag="a">Label X Text</label-x>
```

It renders as follows:

```
<a class="ui label">Label X Text</a>
```

Now let's add a property to that html tag as follows:

```
<label-x tag="a" size="large">Label X Text</label-x>
```

What I want to happen is for the word 'large' to be added to the rendered classes, as follows:

```
<a class="ui label large">Label X Text</a>
```

I can't figure out, though, how to make that happen.  I tried the following, but I got an error:

```
export default {
    props: ['tag', 'type', 'size', 'color', 'direction'],
    render(createElement) {
        return createElement(
            this.tag || 'div',
            {
                class: { this.size },
                attrs: { class: 'ui label'}
            },
            this.$slots.default
        );
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong -- and, more importantly, how can I do it right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should do it.

```
export default {
  props: ['tag', 'type', 'size', 'color', 'direction'],
  render(createElement) {
    // set the default classes
    let classes = ["ui", "label"]
    //check to see if we have a size arrtibute
    if (this.size)
      classes.push(this.size)
    
    return createElement(
      this.tag || 'div',
      {
        attrs: { class: classes.join(" ")}
      },
      this.$slots.default
    );
}
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ZKjmpK?editors=1010).

Though, the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/render-function.html#The-Data-Object-In-Depth) shows a `class` property you can use just like you would if you bound to class:

```
export default {
  props: ['tag', 'type', 'size', 'color', 'direction'],
  render(createElement) {
    let classes = ["ui", "label"]
    if (this.size)
      classes.push(this.size)

    return createElement(
      this.tag || 'div',
      {
        class: classes
      },
      this.$slots.default
    );
  }
```

[Example](https://codepen.io/Kradek/pen/ybqQMM?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks - that works.  One more question, if I may.  Any idea how to do this for multiple props?  I.e., for type, color, size & direction?

Comment: @Moshe You could just check them all the same way assuming they are all classes.